# UnsatisfiedDependencyException occur while executing spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

Can anyone kindly help me to rectify the error?It shows UnsatisfiedDependencyException occur while executing spring-boot and also beanException.

**AdminRepo.java**

```
    package com.adminplan.demo.repository;
    
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
    import com.adminplan.demo.model.Admin;
    
    import java.util.Optional;
    
    public interface AdminRepo extends JpaRepository<Admin,Long> {
        void deleteAdminPlan(Long id);
    
        Optional<Admin> findAdminPlanById(Long id);
    }
```

**AdminService.java**

```
    package com.adminplan.demo.service;
    
    import com.adminplan.demo.exception.UserNotFoundException;
    import com.adminplan.demo.model.Admin;
    import com.adminplan.demo.repository.AdminRepo;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    
    import javax.transaction.Transactional;
    import java.util.List;
    
    @Service
    @Transactional
    public class AdminService {
        private final AdminRepo adminRepo;
    
        @Autowired
        public AdminService(AdminRepo adminRepo) {
            this.adminRepo = adminRepo;
        }
    
        public Admin addAdminPlan(Admin admin) {
            return adminRepo.save(admin);
        }
        public List<Admin> findAllAdminPlan() {return adminRepo.findAll(); }
    
        public Admin updateAdminPlan(Admin adminplan){ return adminRepo.save(adminplan); }
    
        public Admin findAdminPlanById(Long id){
            return adminRepo.findAdminPlanById(id)
                    .orElseThrow(()-> new UserNotFoundException("User by id "+id+" was not found"));
        }
    
        public void deleteAdminPlan(Long id){ adminRepo.deleteAdminPlan(id);}
    }
```

**AdminController.java**

```
    package com.adminplan.demo.controller;
    
    import com.adminplan.demo.model.Admin;
    import com.adminplan.demo.service.AdminService;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
    
    import java.util.List;
    
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/admin-plan")
    public class AdminController {
        private final AdminService adminService;
    
        public AdminController(AdminService adminService) {
            this.adminService = adminService;
        }
    
        @GetMapping("/all")
        public ResponseEntity<List<Admin>> getAllAdminPlan(){
            List<Admin> adminPlans= adminService.findAllAdminPlan();
            return new ResponseEntity<>(adminPlans, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    
        @GetMapping("/find/{id}")
        public ResponseEntity<Admin> getAdminPlanById(@PathVariable("id") Long id){
            Admin adminPlan= adminService.findAdminPlanById(id);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(adminPlan, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    
        @PostMapping("/add-plan")
        public ResponseEntity<Admin> addAdminPlan(@RequestBody Admin admin){
            Admin newAdminPlan = adminService.addAdminPlan(admin);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(newAdminPlan, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }
    
        @PutMapping("/update")
        public ResponseEntity<Admin> updateAdminPlan(@RequestBody Admin admin){
            Admin updatePlan = adminService.updateAdminPlan(admin);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(updatePlan, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    
        @DeleteMapping("/delete/{id}")
        public ResponseEntity<?> deleteAdminPlan(@PathVariable("id") Long id){
            adminService.deleteAdminPlan(id);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    
    
    
    }
```

**application.properties**

```
    # MySQL Configuration
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/adminplan
    spring.datasource.username=****
    spring.datasource.password=****
    spring.jpa.show-sql=true
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

**Error**

```
 

    :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.4)
    
    2022-02-28 14:31:57.433  INFO 1956 --- [           main] com.adminplan.demo.DemoApplication       : Starting DemoApplication using Java 11.0.13 on DESKTOP-MQ2O3FR with PID 1956 (D:\spring boot\admin\target\classes started by keerthi in D:\spring boot\admin)
    2022-02-28 14:31:57.433  INFO 1956 --- [           main] com.adminplan.demo.DemoApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
    2022-02-28 14:31:58.247  INFO 1956 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
    2022-02-28 14:31:58.294  INFO 1956 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 42 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
    2022-02-28 14:31:59.487  INFO 1956 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
    2022-02-28 14:31:59.487  INFO 1956 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
    2022-02-28 14:31:59.487  INFO 1956 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.58]
    2022-02-28 14:31:59.596  INFO 1956 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
    2022-02-28 14:31:59.596  INFO 1956 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2101 ms
    2022-02-28 14:31:59.831  INFO 1956 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
    2022-02-28 14:31:59.877  INFO 1956 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.5.Final
    2022-02-28 14:32:00.018  INFO 1956 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
    2022-02-28 14:32:00.112  INFO 1956 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
    2022-02-28 14:32:00.424  INFO 1956 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
    2022-02-28 14:32:00.440  INFO 1956 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
    2022-02-28 14:32:01.065  INFO 1956 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
    2022-02-28 14:32:01.080  INFO 1956 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
    2022-02-28 14:32:01.440  WARN 1956 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'adminController' defined in file [D:\spring boot\admin\target\classes\com\adminplan\demo\controller\AdminController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'adminService' defined in file [D:\spring boot\admin\target\classes\com\adminplan\demo\service\AdminService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'adminRepo' defined in com.adminplan.demo.repository.AdminRepo defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract void com.adminplan.demo.repository.AdminRepo.deleteAdminPlan(java.lang.Long)! Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract void com.adminplan.demo.repository.AdminRepo.deleteAdminPlan(java.lang.Long)! No property 'deleteAdminPlan' found for type 'Admin'!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract void com.adminplan.demo.repository.AdminRepo.deleteAdminPlan(java.lang.Long)! No property 'deleteAdminPlan' found for type 'Admin'!
    2022-02-28 14:32:01.440  INFO 1956 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
    2022-02-28 14:32:01.440  INFO 1956 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
    2022-02-28 14:32:01.455  INFO 1956 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
    2022-02-28 14:32:01.455  INFO 1956 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
    2022-02-28 14:32:01.471  INFO 1956 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 
    
    Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
    2022-02-28 14:32:01.486 ERROR 1956 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
    
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'adminController' defined in file [D:\spring boot\admin\target\classes\com\adminplan\demo\controller\AdminController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'adminService' defined in file [D:\spring boot\admin\target\classes\com\adminplan\demo\service\AdminService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'adminRepo' defined in com.adminplan.demo.repository.AdminRepo defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract void com.adminplan.demo.repository.AdminRepo.deleteAdminPlan(java.lang.Long)! Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract void com.adminplan.demo.repository.AdminRepo.deleteAdminPlan(java.lang.Long)! No property 'deleteAdminPlan' found for type 'Admin'!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract void com.adminplan.demo.repository.AdminRepo.deleteAdminPlan(java.lang.Long)! No property 'deleteAdminPlan' found for type 'Admin'!
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
        at com.adminplan.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'adminService' defined in file [D:\spring boot\admin\target\classes\com\adminplan\demo\service\AdminService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'adminRepo' defined in com.adminplan.demo.repository.AdminRepo defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract void com.adminplan.demo.repository.AdminRepo.deleteAdminPlan(java.lang.Long)! Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract void com.adminplan.demo.repository.AdminRepo.deleteAdminPlan(java.lang.Long)! No property 'deleteAdminPlan' found for type 'Admin'!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract void com.adminplan.demo.repository.AdminRepo.deleteAdminPlan(java.lang.Long)! No property 'deleteAdminPlan' found for type 'Admin'!
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        ... 19 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'adminRepo' defined in com.adminplan.demo.repository.AdminRepo defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract void com.adminplan.demo.repository.AdminRepo.deleteAdminPlan(java.lang.Long)! Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract void com.adminplan.demo.repository.AdminRepo.deleteAdminPlan(java.lang.Long)! No property 'deleteAdminPlan' found for type 'Admin'!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract void com.adminplan.demo.repository.AdminRepo.deleteAdminPlan(java.lang.Long)! No property 'deleteAdminPlan' found for type 'Admin'!
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        ... 33 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract void com.adminplan.demo.repository.AdminRepo.deleteAdminPlan(java.lang.Long)! Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract void com.adminplan.demo.repository.AdminRepo.deleteAdminPlan(java.lang.Long)! No property 'deleteAdminPlan' found for type 'Admin'!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract void com.adminplan.demo.repository.AdminRepo.deleteAdminPlan(java.lang.Long)! No property 'deleteAdminPlan' found for type 'Admin'!
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException.create(QueryCreationException.java:101) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:106) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1054) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:86) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:86) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:364) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:322) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:230) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:328) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        ... 44 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract void com.adminplan.demo.repository.AdminRepo.deleteAdminPlan(java.lang.Long)! No property 'deleteAdminPlan' found for type 'Admin'!
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:96) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:113) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:254) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:87) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:102) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        ... 66 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property 'deleteAdminPlan' found for type 'Admin'!
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:90) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:437) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:413) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:366) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:330) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:348) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:331) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:249) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:250) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:383) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:384) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:92) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:89) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        ... 70 common frames omitted
    
    
    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Please go through the Above code and help me to correct it.It shows UnsatisfiedDependencyException occur while executing spring-boot and also beanException.

Comment: You do not have any `deleteAdminPlan` propety in the `Admin` entity.

Comment: Also your JPA method should be `Long deleteById(Long id);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `AdminRepo` extends `JpaRepository` - which is a descendant of [CrudRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html)

these methods are already available to AdminRepo

- [findById](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#findById-ID-)
- [deleteById](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#deleteById-ID-)

try removing this method `deleteAdminPlan` and changing AdminController to call the provided `deleteById` method

---

In order to generate the implementation for the Repository methods, spring parses the Repository method names into multiple parts.
see these sections for more detail:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation)

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation